# Need to create a case statement for multiple criteria with varchar and date data types

Tags: sql, case

Need to create a case statement for multiple criteria with varchar and date data types, my code sp far:

```
select 
least(coalesce(case when 1.other_id=10 then 1.datestr else 0 end,
 case  when 2.info='Yes' then 2.date else 0 end))as date1,
from 
test1 as 1
left join test2 as 2 on 1.id = 2.id
```

I essentially want to get the lowest date between 2 conditions. Both conditions have some filters (other_id=10 in first, info="Yes" in second). For those conditions I want to compare least dates.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic:

```
select (case when 1.other_id = 10 and 2.info = 'Yes'
             then least(case when 1.other_id=10 then 1.datestr end,
                        case when 2.info='Yes' then 2.date end
                       )
             when 1.other_id = 10 then 1.date
             else 2.date
        end)
```

Or, you can use more appropriate default values in your expression.  Something like this (it might depend on the database):

```
select least(case when 1.other_id = 10 then 1.datestr else '9999-01-01' end,
             case when 2.info = 'Yes' then 2.date else '9999-01-01' end)
            ) as date1,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gordon, I think the first logic could work,I am fairly new at SQL and would be great if you can help with error,
mismatched input '=' expecting {'.', '[', 'AND', 'AT', 'OR', 'THEN', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '||'}

Comment: @Ron123 . . . I don't know what the error might be.